# Bingbot causing 404 errors

Tags: web-crawler, bing, bingbot

We have recently been seeing a large number of 404 errors that are being created from the Bing web crawler. I have verified that the IP is in fact a Bing machine but just don't know why they are attempting the URL's they are trying. I don't want to use a robots.txt file to just tell them not to crawl my site at all but at the same time I don't want them to continue requesting pages that don't exist. Is there any way to tell where Bing is getting a specific URL from? I tried searching Google using `[link:www.mywebsite.com/pagename/]` and nothing is found which leads me to believe the bot is doing something it isn't supposed to rather than my site having a bad URL.

Comment: What URLs are they requesting? You don't have to say specifically, but please describe if there is anything "meaningful" in them: e.g. is it possible that it was a valid URL at some point?

Comment: The site is driven from database entries so there are links such as www.mysite.com/item/57 but the URL's they are hitting are just www.mystie.com/57. I've tried to find any place where the ID's are located but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Also, those were never valid URLs. Thanks!

Comment: Worst case scenario: it could be an obscure Microsoft bug which your website is triggering somehow. If other crawlers are not picking up those links, then it seems that this is not a faulty back-link issue.

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening on the site I work and only bingbot does this. We have similar URL pattern, like `baseurl/id/name-1`, `baseurl/id/name-2`, etc., but they keep hitting us with invalid requests like `baseurl/id/1`, `baseurl/id/2` (which were never valid) - the solution we have for now is to permanently redirect these requests to `baseurl/id`, which is a valid URL in our case, rather than throwing a 404.