# Bingbot attempting to access non existent pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, bingbot

I recently made some major changes to an ecommerce website that include url structure. The url to view a product is modified by .htaccess and contains a short product description that if changed will not affect the results on the page.

example: `www.Example.com/staticFolder/non-deterministic-product-details/MODEL#.html`

Now in the error log file I am seeing bingbot requesting pages like `example.com/non-deterministic-product-details`

Our sitemaps don't link to this page and I am not able to find any bad links on pages. Has anyone else had problems with bingbot doing this? I found another question that was locked for being random. [Bingbot causing 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687278/bingbot-causing-404-errors). Is it more likely that I am doing something wrong? Should I avoid using psuedo directories in my .htaccess?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing requiring that spiders stick only to link-crawling. It's entirely possible it's guessing URLs which are similar to known ones in the hope that it'll find something.

At any rate, I wouldn't worry about it unless you *know* it's following a bad link. It's quite normal to get lots of requests for non-existent pages.

Comment: I have a similar bot hitting my server for Wordpress Admin pages over and over (it's not a wordpress site). Is there a way I could maybe waste their time, eg forward all that traffic somewhere or such?